# Array-Like (in string) to Array Node.JS request

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I use nodejs with request module to get data from a website

```
request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ufxyz.ufabet.com/_View/RMOdds1Gen.ashx?ot=r&sort=0',
        }, function (error, response, body) {
          body[0];  // it get the first charactor
    });
}
```

which body give a string format array like

```
[[0,'70fc13084d580486','r',0,0,'eng','0',0],[],[],[[[30500,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS',''],[[3852360 ,0 ,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS' ,'30500' ,0,'1 - 0' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,25,0,6271,6272,1,1,7.2,0.25,1,'Georgia U21' ,0,'Lithuania U21' ,1,0,1,1,1.05999994277954,116.800003051758,6.67999982833862,1,6.3,-7.2,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,1.75,9.7,9.4,-9.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,776747107,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4826749,0,'2017-11-14' ,0,'30500|6271|6272' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852730 ,0 ,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS' ,'30500' ,0,'1 - 0' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,25,0,6271,6272,1,1,-8.4,0.5,1,'Georgia U21' ,0,'Lithuania U21' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-9.3,8.4,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,1.5,6.7,-7.6,7.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4826749,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852360,'30500|6271|6272' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852356 ,0 ,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS' ,'30500' ,0,'1 - 3' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,27,0,6240,4051,1,1,-8.5,0.25,0,'Moldova U21' ,0,'Czech Republic U21' ,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,8.5,-9.2,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,4.5,8.9,-9.8,9.8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,914562607,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4826700,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852730,'30500|6240|4051' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852729 ,0 ,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS' ,'30500' ,0,'1 - 3' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,27,0,6240,4051,1,1,-3.5,0,1,'Moldova U21' ,0,'Czech Republic U21' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-4.2,3.5,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,4.75,-7.3,6.4,-6.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4826700,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852356,'30500|6240|4051' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852354 ,3852416 ,'UEFA EUROPEAN U21 CHAMPIONSHIP 2019 QUALIFIERS' ,'30500' ,0,'0 - 0' ,0,1,0,0,'23:59' ,1,25,0,1054,1126,1,1,9.2,1,0,'Estonia U21' ,0,'Iceland U21' ,0,0,1,1,8.15999984741211,1.41999995708466,3.94000005722046,1,-9.2,8.5,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,2,7.3,-8.2,8.2,1,1,8.5600004196167,2.45000004768372,1.75,1,1,0.25,0,1,-9.7,9.7,9.4,1,1,0.5,9.4,9.7,-9.7,212743307,'2017-11-14 23:59:00' ,0,4826732,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852729,'30500|1054|1126' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]],[[4156,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers',''],[[3852874 ,0 ,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers' ,'4156' ,0,'1 - 1' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,22,0,6236,6044,1,1,9.2,0,1,'Greece U19' ,0,'Russia U19' ,0,0,1,1,3.76999998092651,4.30000019073486,1.6599999666214,1,8.3,-9.2,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,2.5,8.8,-9.9,9.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,577582707,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4759425,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852354,'4156|6236|6044' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3853235 ,0 ,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers' ,'4156' ,0,'1 - 1' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,22,0,6236,6044,1,1,-4.8,0.25,1,'Greece U19' ,0,'Russia U19' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-5.7,4.8,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,2.75,-8.1,7,-7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4759425,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852874,'4156|6236|6044' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852876 ,0 ,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers' ,'4156' ,0,'0 - 6' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,22,0,81857,9582,1,1,-7.6,1.5,0,'Gibraltar U19 (n)' ,0,'Romania U19' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7.6,-8.5,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,7.5,9.9,9,-9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,956835307,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,4759426,0,'2017-11-14' ,3853235,'4156|81857|9582' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]],[[27177,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers - Total Corners',''],[[3853657 ,0 ,'UEFA European U19 Championship Qualifiers - Total Corners' ,'27177' ,0,'9 - 0' ,0,1,0,0,'23:00' ,2,22,0,6236,6044,1,0,0,-1,1,'Greece U19' ,0,'Russia U19' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,11.5,7.9,10,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'2017-11-14 23:00:00' ,0,0,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852876,'27177|6236|6044' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]],[[765,'International Friendly U19',''],[[3852665 ,3852666 ,'International Friendly U19' ,'765' ,0,'0 - 1' ,0,1,0,0,'23:59' ,1,23,0,10384,9921,1,1,-8.2,0,1,'Portugal U19' ,0,'Spain U19' ,0,0,1,1,7.44000005722046,1.39999997615814,4,1,-9.1,8.2,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,3,-9.2,8.1,-8.1,1,1,27.6000003814697,1.16999995708466,4.86999988555908,1,1,0,1,1,-8.5,-9.4,8.5,1,1,1.5,-9.3,8.2,-8.2,295357313,'2017-11-14 23:59:00' ,0,4987975,0,'2017-11-14' ,3853657,'765|10384|9921' ,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[3852828 ,3853025 ,'International Friendly U19' ,'765' ,0,'0 - 1' ,0,1,0,0,'23:59' ,1,23,0,10384,9921,1,1,-7.3,0.25,0,'Portugal U19' ,0,'Spain U19' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,7.3,-8.2,'S' ,'S' ,1,1,2.75,7.5,-8.6,8.6,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0.25,0,1,-4.1,4.1,-5,0,1,1.75,-6.1,5,-5,0,'2017-11-14 23:59:00' ,0,4987975,0,'2017-11-14' ,3852665,'765|10384|9921' ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]]],[]]
```

so how could I convert it in to real array object so I can use like body[0].
I've tried to use `JSON.parse` and it got unexpected token error
and even I used

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));
```

the body still returns a string

Comment: This is no valid JSON. JSON uses `"` and not `'` to denote strings. So best option is to fix the server, where you get the data. If this is not possible, a simple `replace()` should do here, but might break in other instances.

Comment: I have tried your response to put into js array object and its works fine for me. What error your are getting? As i can access array object like array[0]

Comment: Are you sure your body object has the response? you might be be using wrong object?

Comment: @Sirko  Thank for that now it work. I replace ' to " and the JSON.parse

Comment: @SirajHussain when I access like array[0] it return the first char
because the body that response is string ' [1,2,3,4] '
so it return [

Comment: It is giving a text response , so the best way would be to parse the text data and break it into multiple arrays and then use that data